# CoSign API: Setting Date Format Using DSS Web Service

Tags: digital-signature, cosign-api

I'm running into a problem when trying to specify the date format for a signature field using the DSS web service. Here is my code:

```
Req = new RequestBaseType();
Req.OptionalInputs = new RequestBaseTypeOptionalInputs();
Req.OptionalInputs.SAPISigFieldSettings = new SAPISigFieldSettingsType();
TimeDateFormatType tf = new TimeDateFormatType();
tf.DateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy";
Req.OptionalInputs.SAPISigFieldSettings.TimeFormat = tf;
```

I attempt to sign the document as follows:

```
DSS service = new DSS();
service.Url = "https://cosign:8080/sapiws/dss.asmx";
SignRequest sreq = new SignRequest();
sreq.InputDocuments = Req.InputDocuments;
sreq.OptionalInputs = Req.OptionalInputs;
Resp = service.DssSign(sreq);
```

And I get the following response from the ResponseBaseType object:

`urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultmajor:Insufficient Information Error parsing OptionalInput SAPISigFieldSettings`

If I don't specify the date format, it works OK. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you want to display just the date and not the time, you need to set `TimeFormat` to an empty string. It is null by default.